# tsql UNION without nulls

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, union, union-all

I have the following query

```
SELECT MONTH, COUNT(DISTINCT VISITS) AS BRAND_VISITS, NULL AS NONB_VISITS
FROM Table1
WHERE KEYWORD_TYPE = BRAND(
AND DATE >= '2013-01-01'
GROUP BY MONTH

UNION ALL

SELECT MONTH, NULL, COUNT(DISTINCT VISITS) AS NONB_VSTS 
FROM Table1
WHERE KEYWORD_TYPE = NON-BRAND
AND DATE >= '2013-01-01'
GROUP BY MONTH
```

I get the following results:

```
1   352540  NULL
2   309834  NULL
3   228764  NULL
4   236054  NULL
5   218096  NULL
6   172527  NULL
1   NULL    5337
2   NULL    14120
3   NULL    9954
4   NULL    23755
5   NULL    19771
6   NULL    30797
```

However, what I want is inline results without NULLS

```
1   352540  5337
2   309834  14120
3   228764  9954
4   236054  23755
5   218096  19771
6   172527  30797
```

Comment: It looks like what you need is a JOIN, not a UNION.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I disagree, union can easily be used here, join can cause some problems with months with 0 counts, although it is not likely to happen in this example

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with using a single statement with CASE or with an JOIN on month instead of a UNION.  If you take the join approach you may need to account for null values (no visist for a keyword in a month). You will want to profile them to see which is faster with your data and table structure.  It is really all about the indexes and the amount of data you need to aggregate.

Assuming you don't have to worry about nulls based on the counts in your example, here is what you want.

```
SELECT brand.month, brand.brand_visits,nonbrand.non_brand_visits
FROM (SELECT month, COUNT(visits) AS brand_visits
      FROM Table1
      WHERE keyword_type = 'BRAND'
      AND date >= '2013-01-01'
      GROUP BY month) brand
INNER JOIN
      (SELECT month, COUNT(visits) AS non_brand_visits 
       FROM Table1
       WHERE keyword_type = 'NON-BRAND'
       AND date >= '2013-01-01'
       GROUP BY month) nonbrand 
ON brand.month=nonbrand.month
```

Here is the CASE approach.  You should profile based on your actual data you are aggregating and your indexes to see which method is faster.

```
SELECT month, 
SUM(CASE WHEN keyword_type = 'BRAND' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS brand_visits, 
SUM(CASE WHEN keyword_type = 'NON-BRAND' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS non_brand_visits 
FROM Table1
WHERE date >= '2013-01-01'
GROUP BY month
```

Finally, you did not provide table structure or example data so I made some assumptions above.  I strongly believe you did not need the `COUNT(DISTINCT` in your original statement.  I have removed it and verified the two statement above yield the same results.  If `COUNT(DISTINCT` is required then the CASE approach will not work but the join approach will still work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Using your columns:

```
SELECT month, 
count(distinct CASE WHEN keyword_type = 'BRAND' THEN visits END) AS BRAND_VISITS, 
count(distinct CASE WHEN keyword_type = 'NON-BRAND' THEN visits END) AS NONB_VSTS  
FROM Table1
WHERE date >= '2013-01-01'
and keyword_type in ('BRAND','NON-BRAND')
GROUP BY month
```

Am tempted to believe that month is simply the month from the date column, I would prefer this solution, it con cover more years than 1 and the same query will still be valid in the year 2014

```
SELECT cast(dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, date), 0) as date) month, 
count(distinct CASE WHEN keyword_type = 'BRAND' THEN visits END) AS BRAND_VISITS, 
count(distinct CASE WHEN keyword_type = 'NON-BRAND' THEN visits END) AS NONB_VSTS 
FROM Table1
WHERE date >= '2013-01-01'
and keyword_type in ('BRAND','NON-BRAND')
GROUP BY datediff(month, 0, date)
```

If you want to stick with your old script, you can fix it this way:

```
SELECT MONTH, max(BRAND_VISITS) BRAND_VISITS, max(NONB_VISITS) NONB_VISITS 
FROM
(
SELECT MONTH, COUNT(DISTINCT VISITS) AS BRAND_VISITS, NULL AS NONB_VISITS
FROM Table1
WHERE KEYWORD_TYPE = 'BRAND'
AND DATE >= '2013-01-01'
GROUP BY MONTH
UNION ALL
SELECT MONTH, NULL, COUNT(DISTINCT VISITS) AS NONB_VSTS 
FROM Table1
WHERE KEYWORD_TYPE = 'NON-BRAND'
AND DATE >= '2013-01-01'
GROUP BY MONTH
) a
GROUP BY MONTH
```